# Limit of $\frac{\cos(ax)-\cos(bx)}{\cos(cx)-\cos(dx)}$ as $x$ approaches to $0$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity, limits-without-lhopital

Limit of $$\frac{\cos(ax)-\cos(bx)}{\cos(cx)-\cos(dx)}$$ as $x$ approaches to $0$.

I have calculated this limit using L Hospital's rule to be $$ \frac{-a^2+b^2}{-c^2+d^2}$$
But on the book the limit is given to be  $$ \frac{a^2-b^2}{c^2-d^2}$$
Please help me understand what is the actual limit.

Comment: Note that

$$\frac{-a^2+b^2}{-c^2+d^2}=\frac{-1}{-1}\cdot\frac{-a^2+b^2}{-c^2+d^2}=\frac{a^2-b^2}{c^2-d^2}$$

Comment: I suggest applying $\cos x-\cos y=2\sin{x+y\over 2}\sin {y-x\over 2}$ and the limit ${\sin t\over t}$ as $t\to 0.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Or also $\cos (ax) =1-2\sin^2(ax/2)$ etc with the same standard limit.

Comment: @user Your way requires more effort as you need to apply also  the formulas  for $\sin x+\sin y$ and $\sin x-\sin y.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc No we can conclude directly. I add a solution by that step.

Comment: @user You are right, no further formulas are needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two expressions given are exactly the same. Observe that \begin{align*}
\frac{-a^2 + b^2}{-c^2 + d^2} &= \frac{-a^2 + b^2}{-c^2 + d^2} \times \frac{-1}{-1} \\ &= \frac{-(-a^2+b^2)}{-(-c^2+d^2)} \\ &= \frac{a^2 - b^2}{c^2 - d^2}.\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

As noticed your solution is fine, note also that we can avoid l'Hospital by standard limit $\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2} \to \frac12$

$$\frac{\cos(ax)-\cos(bx)}{\cos(cx)-\cos(dx)}=\frac{\cos(ax)-1+1-\cos(bx)}{\cos(cx)-1+1-\cos(dx)}=$$

$$=\frac{a^2\frac{\cos(ax)-1}{a^2x^2}+b^2\frac{1-\cos(bx)}{b^2x^2}}{c^2\frac{\cos(cx)-1}{c^2x^2}+d^2\frac{1-\cos(dx)}{d^2x^2}} \to\frac{-\frac12 a^2+\frac12 b^2}{-\frac12 c^2+\frac12d^2}=\frac{- a^2+b^2}{- c^2+d^2}=\frac{a^2-b^2}{c^2-d^2}$$

---

As an alternative using that $\cos (ax) =1-2\sin^2(ax/2)$ etc.

$$\ldots=\frac{-\frac{a^2}4\frac{\sin^2(ax/2)}{a^2x^2/4}+\frac{b^2}4\frac{\sin^2(bx/2)}{b^2x^2/4}}{-\frac{c^2}4\frac{\sin^2(cx/2)}{c^2x^2/4}+\frac{d^2}4\frac{\sin^2(dx/2)}{d^2x^2/4}} \to \frac{a^2-b^2}{c^2-d^2}$$